# Change global variable of a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim

I am using the functionality from the following script of the `gensim` package: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/3.8.0/gensim/summarization/keywords.py

How can I change the global variables `WINDOW_SIZE`, etc. before invoking the function `keywords()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from gensim.summarization.keywords import WINDOW_SIZE, keywords

WINDOW_SIZE = <whatever value you want>

k = keywords(...)
```

Comment: I don't think this will do what they want. `keywords` will still see the old value of `WINDOW_SIZE`.

Answer (score 0):

Import the module with a name, then re-assign it in the module object:

```
import gensim.summarization.keywords as kw

kw.WINDOW_SIZE = new_value
kw.keywords()
```